# SendMessage to TextBox Window Child in C++ not working

Tags: c++, winapi

```
char arbc[60];
cout << "Message: ";
cin.getline(arbc+'\0',sizeof(arbc)+1);
system("pause");
PostMessage(hwndch,WM_SETTEXT,(WPARAM)*arbc,0);
```

So hwndch is a window child and the child is a textbox, it's parent is the main window form. The problem is that WM_SETTEXT isn't setting the text of the textbox to the string of characters. I know it's not a problem with the windowchild because WM_CHAR outputs at least 1 character in the textbox.
Note: I'm modifying the handles of another process.

Comment: You didn't follow the documentation and have mixed up `wParam` and `lParam`. The latter also expects a pointer null-terminated string, not a character masquerading as a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `PostMessage` with `WM_SETTEXT`. That's a synchronous message. Your problem is even greater when the window is in a different process. The system needs to marshal the text from your process into another process. It cannot do that with an asynchronous message.

Use `SendMessage` instead.

Your other problems include at least the following:

- The `wParam` argument is wrong. That parameter is ignored. Pass `(LPARAM)arbc` to `lParam` instead. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632644.aspx) is quite clear.
- You should not use C strings in any case. Use `std::string`, and then `c_str()`.
- Your use of `sizeof` is wrong. Your use of `getline` is all wrong too.
- You seem confused over which function you are calling. The title says `SendMessage`, the code says `PostMessage`.

You probably want something along these lines:

```
std::cout << "Message: ";
std::string msg;
std::getline(std::cin, msg);
SendMessage(hwndch, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)msg.c_str());
```

Comment: Don't forget the `arbc+'\0'` construct.

Comment: @Herr What about it? It appears to be nonsense to me

Comment: Yeah that was the point... to the OP: you're adding the numeric value of the character to your pointer, not null-terminating the string as you probably intended.